# Node.JS add script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create something in Node.JS. I got the server started and a request to index.html. In index.html I got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
    <button id="login">Login</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my scripts/main.js file I got this:

```
var socket = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').click(login);
});

function login()
{
    socket = io();

    socket.emit('set-name', {name: $('#name').val()});
};
```

In my app.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/scipts/'));
```

Where

```
var app = require('express')();
```

However, my browser complains that main.js file isn't found... I don't have much experience with it, so how can I fix this?

This is my project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Comment: can you show us the hierarchy of your node app ?

Comment: What does the server look like? are you using a static file folder middleware?

Comment: what is your route

Comment: Why should `main.js` be found? You haven't shown us any code that would serve it.

Comment: Added project structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/scipts/'));` with `app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/scripts/'));`

For path concatenation please consider to use [path.join](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path) as environment independent method.

Answer (score -2):

You need to get rid of the forward slash in your script declaration:

```
<script src="/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: This assumes that your scripts folder is in the same location as your index.html file.